# Mecanismo de busca se comporta igual utilizando multi-thread ou uma única thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

Boa tarde,
Estou desenvolvendo uma rotina para fazer pesquisa em arquivos pdf. Minha ideia é distribuir o processamento da busca em cada arquivo em threads diferentes para otimizar o tempo de resposta. O método SearchPDFText abaixo pesquisa e retorna os arquivos corretamente, porém quando eu faço um teste processando os arquivos em threads diferentes e outro teste processando um a um na thread principal da aplicação o tempo médio de resposta é o mesmo.

```
    int ctFilesToSearch;
    int ctFilesSearching;

    /// <summary>
    /// Files where the search text was found.
    /// </summary>
    List<FileInfo> lFilesGood;
    Queue<FileInfo> qFilesToSearch;

    public SearchEngine()
    {
        lFilesGood = new List<FileInfo>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<FileInfo> SearchPDFText(IEnumerable<FileInfo> lFiles, string searchText)
    {
        try
        {
            qFilesToSearch = new Queue<FileInfo>(lFiles);
            int totalFiles = lFiles.Count();
            ctFilesToSearch = totalFiles;
            ctFilesSearching = 0;

            while (ctFilesSearching < totalFiles)
            {
                ctFilesSearching++;
                Thread tr = new Thread(() => Search(qFilesToSearch.Dequeue(), searchText));
                tr.Start(); //Multi thread.
                //Search(qFilesToSearch.Dequeue(), searchText); //Processamento 1 a 1.
            }

            while (ctFilesToSearch > 0) ; //Aguarda todos os arquivos a serem processados.
            return lFilesGood;
        }
        catch { throw; }
    }

    private void Search(FileInfo file, string searthText)
    {
        if (SearchPdfFile(file.FullName, searthText))
            lFilesGood.Add(file);
        ctFilesToSearch--;
    }

    private bool SearchPdfFile(string fileName, string searthText)
    {
        bool textFound = false;
        if (File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileName))
            {
                for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
                {
                    ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();

                    string currentPageText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy);
                    if (currentPageText.Contains(searthText))
                    {
                        textFound = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return textFound;
    }
```

Obs.: Estou utilizando as seguintes dlls:

```
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
```

Meu teste foi baseado no processamento de 200 arquivos .pdf com 16 páginas cada. O tempo de resposta em ambos os cenários foi em média 1m 40s. Eu esperava que por estar processando de forma paralela o resultado seria muito melhor. A forma que estou fazendo para alcançar meu objetivo (paralelismo) está correta?

Comment: Esse método SearchPdfFile faz uma tarefe I/O Bound?

Comment: @GabrielColetta, o método SearchPdfFile utiliza a dll iTextSharp para abrir o pdf e localizar o searchText. Eu utilizo apenas o método File.Exists da classe System.IO.

Comment: Só para entender a diferença entre sua expectativa e a realidade, de que forma você imaginou que dividir o trabalho em mais de uma thread poderia melhorar o "tempo de resposta"?

Comment: com base na quantidade de pdfs a analisar,  talvez ficaria mais eficiente se em vez de colocar varias threads para um só pdf, colocar uma thread para cada pdf e ir pulando para os próximos assim que acabar!

Comment: O problema é o seguinte: 200 registros para encontrar é considerado pouco registro, sendo em Thread ou não. O problema surge quando você começa fazer leitura dos arquivos em um disco. Esse processo é considerado I/O bound, então a sua thread vai ficar ociosa esperando por seu resultado para depois continuar o processamento. O que eu recomendo se quer uma melhor performance é trabalhar com programação assincronia, assim eu posso continuar fazendo algum processo enquanto o arquivo é buscado.

Comment: @Bacco, minha ideia era ter vários arquivos sendo pesquisados "ao mesmo tempo", ao invés de esperar terminar a busca em um arquivo para então iniciar a busca no próximo arquivo.

Comment: @Lodi, foi isso mesmo que fiz... Cada arquivo está sendo pesquisado em uma única thread. Não quero esperar acabar a busca em um arquivo para então iniciar o próximo, mas sim pesquisar vários arquivos paralelamente.

Comment: @GabrielColetta, 200 arquivos eu usei para teste... Em produção pode chegar a 2Gb de arquivos pdf... Eu imaginei que a forma que fiz seria assíncrona uma vez que ao chamar tr.Start() o sistema continua o processamento sem ficar aguardando um retorno. Não é?

Comment: O pc não faz nada "ao mesmo tempo", ele simplesmente "divide a atenção" quando você cria threads. Imagine um empacotador de café em uma esteira, embalando caixas. Quando você cria uma nova "thread", o mesmo operador passa a cuidar de duas esteiras. Eventualmente você pode ter um melhor uso de vários _cores_ do mesmo PC num cenário assim, mas só se desconsiderar as outras coisas que a máquina já tem, pra fazer. E mesmo assim, cada funcionário (core) precisa estar cuidando da sua própria esteira. (ok, eu simplifiquei em demasia, mas deixemos as tecnicidades pra quem for responder oficialmente).

Comment: @RaphaSheep Não necessariamente. O Search() será executado em uma thread como você comenta, porém vai chegar um momento que essa thread vai chamar um método I/O Bound (fazer a leitura do arquivo, por exemplo), onde ela vai ficar esperando esse arquivo ser carregado para depois continuar. Esse é provavelmente o motivo ao qual fazer de maneira sequencial ou concorrente não esta dando diferença significativa.

Comment: @GabrielColetta, entendi, muito obrigado pela explicação. Então qual seria a melhor opção para otimizar o tempo de resposta no meu cenário? Talvez utilizando Task ao invés de Thread?? Ou não mudaria nada?